# Ubuntu GUI crashed

Tags: unity, 13.04, xorg

I was trying to install the copy.com client for linux. I was copying the libraries for it into `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` when the screen went black. I have done a hard shutdown and turned the computer back on and it says it is in low graphics mode. If I try to use any of the options the screen goes black again. I did a `Ctrl-Alt-F1` to get to console mode and I have logged on. What do I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you corrupted some libraries, especially the way Unity will misbehave some Ubuntu prepackaged apps.

## I recommend replacing Unity with Gnome using the following

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cinnamon nemo

xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false

gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true

xdg-open $HOME

sudo apt-get autoremove --purge unity unity-common unity-services unity-lens-* unity-scope-* unity-webapps-* gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6* libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt* overlay-scrollbar* activity-log-manager-control-center firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-websites-integration

sudo apt-get autoremove --purge activity-log-manager-common python-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub

sudo apt-get install bleachbit

sudo reboot

==============================Or reinstall Unity===================================

sudo apt-get install --reinstall --fix-broken --autoremove --yes  unity unity-common unity-services unity-lens-* unity-scope-* unity-webapps-* gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6* libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt* overlay-scrollbar* activity-log-manager-control-center firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-websites-integration